# MS Access SQL - update row with current db time

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access

I'm using MS Access mdb as a database for my C# application. I need my application to update a row every few seconds and I want it to save the database's current time into the lastUpdate field. I don't want to start writing the code before I'm sure which method I should use.

So, in the UPDATE SET command, should I use NOW(), GETDATE(), CURRENT_DATE(), CURTIME() or something else?

Example (correct?):

```
UPDATE UsersSignedIn SET lastUpdate = NOW() WHERE appUserName = ?
```

Thanks in advance for your advice!

Comment: Your example should work fine, have you tried it?

Comment: Yes. After reading the answer here I proceeded to write the whole algorithm to sign in users and update their signed status and it's working. Thanks for the help.

Comment: `CURRENT_DATE()` is standard SQL, granular to one day. `GETDATE()` is SQL Server proprietary, granular to sub-second. `CURTIME()` is mySQL proprietary, granular to one(?) second. `NOW()` is MS Access proprietary, granular to one second. `DATE()` is MS Access proprietary, granular to one day.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes in MS-Access you have to use `NOW()` function because there isn't `GETDATE()` .